# Subtracting rasters using gdal_calculate command?

Tags: raster, gdal, command-line

How do I subtract two raster using gdal_calculate command?

Note that gdal_calc is different from gdal_calculate.py.

The rasters I am using have different dimensions.

### Note the utility this question refers to is no longer maintained.  See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159694/2856) for a `gdal_calc` method.

Answer (score 6):

Just worked out how to do this with gdal_calc.py - to get around issues with files with different dimensions (and resolutions) you can use a VRT.

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate combined.vrt dem1.tif dem2.tif
gdal_calc.py -A combined.vrt -A_band=1 -B combined.vrt -B_band=2 --calc="A-B" --outfile diff.tif
```

Comment: One small change here is that "-A_band" should actually have two dashes before it, like "--A_band".

Answer (score 4):

## Note the utility this answer refers to is no longer maintained. Use `gdal_calc` or `rio calc` instead.

The basic syntax is similar to `gdal_calc.py`

i.e.

```
gdal_calculate -a a.tif -b b.tif --calc="a - b" --outfile c.tif
```

If your input rasters are unsigned (i.e Byte or UInt16 etc) and the result may contain negative values, you need to specifically cast to a signed type :

```
gdal_calculate -a a.tif -b b.tif --calc="Int16(a) - b" --outfile c.tif
```

If your rasters are multiband, you need to specify the band (unless you want multiband output)

```
gdal_calculate -a a.tif -b b.tif --calc="Int16(a[0]) - b[0]" --outfile c.tif
```

If your rasters have defined NoData values, use the `--nodata` flag. You don't need to specify the NoData values as the script will determine them from the rasters:

```
gdal_calculate --nodata -a a.tif -b b.tif --calc="Int16(a) - b" --outfile c.tif
```

Comment: What if -a has a nodata value of -32767 and -b has a nodata value of -3.40282e+38?

Comment: I tried to load the raster in qgis and check the properties under transparency and observed the nodata value box has been marked x and it says -nodata value is -32767. Is that what you meant with `as long as it's defined as nodata`?

Comment: I don't know how qgis determines nodata. If `gdalinfo` says the nodata value is -32767 then the script will use that value.

Comment: Can I use gdal_calculate in batch processing?

Comment: Yes. But if you know python it's probably easier to use the API https://code.google.com/p/gdal-calculations/wiki/CalculationsLibrary

Answer (score 2):

On the [help page](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) an example is given:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"
```

This is addition, but subtraction is just as easy:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A-B"
```

Comment: gdal_calc is different from gdal_calculate. Tried gdal_calc and it is only applicable to raster with the same dimensions.

Comment: Fair enough. Surely though the answer would only be valid where there is overlap, you can extract using GDAL_Translate with -projwin switch to get rasters the same dimension. Are their pixel sizes the same?

Comment: the 3 A raster has this pixel sizes, Pixel Size = (0.009474281391831,-0.009489211800969) Pixel Size = (0.009698025551684,-0.009698469846985) Pixel Size = (0.011755044580009,-0.011769524849809) while the B raster has it's fixed pixel size which is Pixel Size = (0.010067480700000,-0.010067480700000). What should I do?

Comment: Conceivably you could resample all rasters to match the largest cell size as this is the least accurate. GDAL_Translate will do that too.

Comment: Can I used gdalwarp in resampling?or just the gdal_translate?

Comment: Warp can resample as well. I would use translate to do it all in one operation either [-outsize xsize[%] ysize[%]] or [-tr xres yres] and specify the resample method with [-r {nearest,bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}] as you're already doing -projwin to extract a sample. GDAL_Calculate code is available and it looks like it's similar to the calc python tool. https://code.google.com/p/gdal-calculations/source/browse/trunk/lib/gdal_calculations/gdal_calculate.py?spec=svn55&r=55

Comment: Yes that is what I'm talking about, gdal_calculate. I think it can perform calculations even if the raster have different dimensions. But I just don't know how to do it specifically how to subtract. Because the example showed isn't just subtracting.

Comment: I'm not sure. The code looks similar; I can't tell if it will perform calculations on different dimension/cell size rasters (I haven't used NumPy much).

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson I see that -tr is announced with GDAL 2.0 version of gdal_translate. Do you know when this version will be released ?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Just for clarification, sorry. If I'm going to use the gdal_translate should I used the pixel size for the xsize[%] and ysize[%]? Like `-outsize 0.010067480700000 -0.010067480700000?

Comment: Outsize is in rows and columns. From http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html : -outsize xsize[%] ysize[%]: Set the size of the output file. **Outsize is in pixels and lines** unless '%' is attached in which case it is as a fraction of the input image size. Set it so the number of rows and columns is identical for all your rasters.  @radouxju, I'm not keeping up with release dates but update from time to time when I've got a quiet moment or two.